# conditional html without javascript: why can't I see my html code

Tags: html, firefox

i tried just this:

```
<table><tr><td>
    <!--[if !IE]>
    non ie browser
   <![endif]--> 
</tr></td></table>
```

on firefox I can't see what I expect: "non ie browser"

why?

Comment: Perhaps because you're hiding the string `"non ie browser"` in comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<!--[if !IE]> <--> Not IE  <!--> <![endif]-->
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

Conditional comments are supported by IE only, so you can't use "negative conditions" like this.

You'd have to work around it e.g. by defining CSS in the conditional comment that makes element "a" visible and element "b" invisible, while the standard CSS says vice versa.